# Force Matching in Coarse Grained Molecular Dynamics with Jax - Forces do not match when neglecting energy loss

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convergence, graph-neural-network

I am currently exploring force matching approaches for molecular dynamic simulations.
As I am still in an exploration state, I'd tried investigated

[Force Matching Neural Network Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/jax-md/blob/master/notebooks/neural_networks.ipynb#scrollTo=DrmKVE6lCQz_)

corresponding to
[Unveiling the predictive power of static structure in glassy systems](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-020-0842-8).

They train a graph neural network to match to estimate forces from positions.

Therefore, they calculate a loss where they match energy and forces.

Loss = $(energy_{predicted} - energy_{target})^2 + ( Forces_{predicted} - Forces_{target})^2$

where the Energy is defined as $U(x,\phi)$ and the force is defined as $-\frac{dU}{dx} = F$.

When neglecting the energy loss and purely matching forces, the prediction seems to converge to 0. This is not intuitive, as [Coarse Graining Molecular Dynamics with Graph Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.11412) seem to train their GNN just with Force matching. The question is: Does anybody knows why the neural networks behave like this.

To reproduce my observations:

Change the loss-function in [1](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/jax-md/blob/master/notebooks/neural_networks.ipynb#scrollTo=DrmKVE6lCQz_) to:

```
@jit
def loss(params, R, targets):
  return force_loss(params, R, targets[1])
```

and the training to:

```
train_epochs = 20

opt_state = opt.init(params)

train_energy_error = []
test_energy_error = []

for iteration in range(train_epochs):
  train_energy_error += [float(np.sqrt(force_loss(params, batch_Rs[0], batch_Fs[0])))]
  test_energy_error += [float(np.sqrt(force_loss(params, test_positions, test_forces)))]
 
  draw_training(params)

  params, opt_state = update_epoch((params, opt_state), 
                                   (batch_Rs, (batch_Es, batch_Fs)))

  onp.random.shuffle(lookup)
  batch_Rs, batch_Es, batch_Fs = make_batches(lookup)
```

as well as the visualization of the trainging:

```
 def draw_training(params):
  display.clear_output(wait=True)
  display.display(plt.gcf())
  plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
  plt.semilogy(train_energy_error)
  plt.semilogy(test_energy_error)
  plt.xlim([0, train_epochs])
  format_plot('Epoch', '$L$')
  plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
  predicted = vmap(force_fn, (None, 0))(params, example_positions).reshape((-1,))
  plt.plot(example_forces.reshape((-1,)), predicted, 'o')
  #plt.plot(np.linspace(-400, -300, 10), np.linspace(-400, -300, 10), '--')
  format_plot('$E_{label}$', '$E_{prediction}$')
  finalize_plot((2, 1))
  plt.show()
```

to reproduce my observations.